# Php unix timestamp with strtotime

Tags: php, unix, timestamp, strtotime

I start learn PHP and is very clear I make some error here, I try obtain Unix timestamp of specific hour and minutes of the day:

```
 <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
 $data = new DateTime();
 $datafmt = $data->format('Y-m-d');
 echo strtotime($datafmt,'18:30:00');
 ?>
```

The code return `1554951600`   and is equal to:

```
GMT: Thursday, April 11, 2019 3:00:00 AM
Your time zone: Thursday, April 11, 2019 12:00:00 AM GMT-03:00
```

This is wrong, timestamp should be:
  `1555018200`   is equal to:

```
GMT: Thursday, April 11, 2019 9:30:00 PM
Your time zone: Thursday, April 11, 2019 6:30:00 PM GMT-03:00
```

What I doing wrong?

---

Fixed!

```
echo strtotime($datafmt. '18:30:00');
```

`,` instead `.`   that is my error!

Comment: Why are you mixing `DateTime` with `strtotime()`? Why are you even using `strtotime()` at all?

Comment: Fixed.
echo strtotime($dataformat,'18:30:00');   
Should be

echo strtotime($datafmt. '18:30:00');

That is my error.
Now code return 1555018200   : )

John I learning php, probably I do a lot of incorrect things on the road :)
I can showme better way of do what this code do, I really appreciate in order to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `strtotime()` at all. `DateTime` class is a replacement and is more powerful. Just pass the time to the constructor or set it with the method `setTime()`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
$data = new DateTime('18:30:00');
// Alternative ways to set the time of the DateTime object
// $data->setTime('18', '30', '00');
// $data->setTime(...explode(':', '18:30:00'));
$datafmt = $data->format('U'); // U means UNIX timestamp
echo $datafmt;
```